# rdbm normalisation for table

Tags: mysql, sql, dependencies, rdbms

I am new to mysql and rdbms and I need help to create normalised database for the table below
[image]

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which field is your primary key ?

Comment: @NullSoulException This table uses a composite primary key

Comment: Which fields are they ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for tables you can combine.
What does a Invoice contain?
well, an INV_NUM, Prod_NUM, Sale_Date, Quant_Sold.(first table: Invoice)
second table(Product): Prod_Num, Prod_Label, Prod_Price and Vend_code
third table(Vendor): Vend_Code, Vend Name

Then when you generate a "real" invoice you can connect all the data and generate the file.

What you should keep in mind, that every table has at least a Primary key (an identifier often tablename_ID) and a Foreign Key.

In the Invoice table the primary key is Inv_NUM and the Prod_Num is a foreign key.

hope you find this useful

Comment: Dont we need another table between prod and inv to create many to many rel? Or just foreign key between them

Comment: I think not. Because you always have 1 (invoice) to many (products). and not vice versa. Think of your database in helicopter-view. from your invoice it contains a lot of products.

Comment: So a product can cannot appear on more than 1 invoice? How can that product be ordered again?

Comment: Yes it can appear on more than 1 invoice. because you have more of it in stock. You have (for example) only 1 Rotary sander. so this sander can only be on 1 invoice. If you have 2 in stock, you can have 2 invoices with 1 sanders, or 1 invoice with 2 sanders

Comment: I think that the invoice is actually the connecting table between the many to many relation